# Short cut key to put cursor in recaptcha box

Tags: shortcuts, captcha

Is there a shortcut key that will put the cursor back in the recaptcha box?

Comment: Is this in an application, a web page, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a site specific function methinks.  hitting tab a few times ought to get you there, though.